# Не изменяются стили в браузере при изменении их в файле стилей, подключенном к шаблону на Flask(Python 3.7)

Tags: python, flask

В приложении `app.py`на Flask (Python 3.7) существует файл шаблона `index.html`. При первоначальном подключении файла `style.css` к фалу шаблона `index.html` все срабатывает нормально. Если изменить значения стилей в файле стилей, в браузере изменения не происходят. При изменении названия файла стилей первый раз все срабатывает, а потом все повторяется. Как я понимаю, значения стилей сохраняются в кэше браузера и не обновляются при повторной загрузке. Можно ли как то автоматизировать очистку или обновление кэша браузера без захода в настройки браузера? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Доступный вам максимум - это добавлять к ссылкам на статические ресурсы параметр с версией.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev. Спасибо за ответ. Уточню. То есть при изменениях в программе нужно каждый раз заходить в настройки браузера и вручную очищать кэш?

Comment: Либо каждый раз исправлять шаблон и перезапускать сервис.